# What happens if a list Welcome Email is triggered to a user who is unsubscribed?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, list

I'm attaching a welcome email to a list and using as a confirmation email. What happens if someone enters a list via Web Collect but is unsubscribed? Will the "welcome email" successfully send as a transactional email? If not, is there a way I can make it transactional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the [Send Classification](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/send_classifications/).

If the email is set to *Transactional*, it'll get sent.  If it's *Commercial*, then they won't get it.

It also depends on what the subscribers is unsubscribed *from*. If they're globally unsubscribed, then they won't get it.  If they're unsubscribed from the [List](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/lists/) (or [Publication](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/publication_lists/)) associated with the send, then they won't get it.